# Can't read files from internal storage..?

Tags: android, file

I can't read the files in my internal phone's directory i.e.  /sdcard/Android/data/com.proj.p/files/FILENAME ..please tell me how to read the files from there..?

Comment: "can't receive the files" is a completely useless description of your symptoms.

Comment: Post the code you use to try to read the file(s)

Comment: got the solution @DavidWasser thnks for replyin..:)

Answer (score 2):

the sdcard directory is NOT internal storage. it's external. make sure your manifest has the EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: could you post your manifest and the code that tries to read and any stack traces from errors reading it

Comment: hey sorry @toadzky...got the solution actually it was stored in my external storage and my phone's card was again and again getting demounted....thnks:)